# systemctl failed to connect to bus - docker ubuntu:16.04 container

Tags: server, 16.04, systemd, docker

I'm trying to use the `systemctl` command in a `ubuntu:16.04` docker container. I'm running the following command...

```
systemctl status ssh
```

However I'm getting the error...

```
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

Why is this not working? Is this related to Ubuntu running in a docker container? How can I get `systemctl` to work correctly?

Comment: Use `service ssh start`

Comment: For those who have the same problem with `sudo systemctl --user` ... just remove the `sudo` !

Comment: Holy shit. I had `systemctl` aliased to `sudo systemctl --no-pager`. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I assume you start your docker container with something like

```
docker run -t -i ubuntu:16.04 /bin/bash
```

The problem now is that your init process PID 1 is `/bin/bash`, not systemd.
Confirm with `ps aux`.

In addition to that you are missing dbus, which would be the way to communicate. This is where your error message is coming from. But as your PID 1 is not systemd, it will not help to install dbus.

Best would be to re-think the way you plan to use docker. Do not rely on systemd as a process manager but have the docker container run your desired application in the foreground.

Comment: Services like openssh-server are configured to log to the default syslog facility. How can I get sshd logs without relying on systemctl?

Comment: @ParthShah please check out sshd man page. Mine has the following options: By caling it with -D you can keep it in the foreground. with -e you instruct it to directly print the logs. these can then later be inspected the docker way with `docker log`.

Comment: [FYI] was getting this error with `/sbin/init` being PID=1 process. Adding `--privileged=true` as suggested by @sonjaya sonjaya below solved the isssue.

Comment: beautiful answer!!

Answer (score 21):

Others have reported a similar problem. Start up the terminal and type:

```
$ env
```

Do you see an environment variable like this?

```
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/`id -u`
```

Where `id -u` is enclosed in backticks not single quotes. This variable is reinterpreted into a number usually `1000` for regular users and `0` for super user (sudo).

If the environment variable `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` does not exist you need to create it. The full discussion is in [launchpad systemd answers](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+question/287454).

Comment: I tried this without success. As my Ubuntu 16.04 instance has the form of a docker container and I have not set up any users I am working as `root`, so I used the variable `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/root/0`, without success. Then I checked the folder `/run` and found that there is no subfolder `/run/root`. Is there anyway I can get a more verbose error message? I had a look at `systemctl --help` but couldn't see a way of getting detailed error messages.

Comment: I am having the same issue and this also did not resolve my problem.  Did you ever figure this one out @DuncanGravill

Comment: @Roeland Yes. I asked a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39169403/systemd-and-systemctl-within-ubuntu-docker-images) on SO which had a stronger response. Also I recommend watching the Self-Paced tutorials on the Docker website. It is explained (slightly vaguely) in those videos how `PID 1` which is usually `systemd` is replaced in a Docker container with the container **Entrypoint**.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! I needed this to start/manage a user unit from a system unit.

Comment: @DuncanGravill  that's because the directory should be `/run/user/0` and not `/run/root/0`

Answer (score 14):

Just start the `dbus` service:

```
/etc/init.d/dbus start
```

Comment: I am building a custom container solution and ran into the problem that pihole would not install, complaining about systemd not being used as init system. Manually starting `dbus` did resolve this :)

Answer (score 9):

If you're getting this error in the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), I've found it's because Docker is unsupported. This is due to lack of cgroups and other prerequisites.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
docker run -ti -d --privileged=true images_docker  "/sbin/init"
```

or

```
docker run -ti -d --privileged=true images_docker
```

will be same result.

Here I get from the [doc of Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities):

> By default, Docker containers are “unprivileged” and cannot, for example, run a Docker daemon inside a Docker container. This is because by default a container is not allowed to access any devices, but a “privileged” container is given access to all devices (see the documentation on cgroups devices).
>
> When the operator executes docker run --privileged, Docker will enable access to all devices on the host as well as set some configuration in AppArmor or SELinux to allow the container nearly all the same access to the host as processes running outside containers on the host. Additional information about running with --privileged is available on the Docker Blog.

Comment: Could you explain your command and the difference to the [accepted question](https://askubuntu.com/a/952106/250300)?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Thank you for trying to help! A quick review of [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/docker/#child-commands) leads me to believe you may have made an error or 2 in this command. If you would be so kind as to [edit] it and explain what you are doing and how it solves the problem, ping me and I'll come back and give you an upvote!

Comment: When you say images_docker, do you mean the vanilla ubuntu:16.04? Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

You may not be running *systemd*, which is the default implementation of *init* on 16.04. If you upgraded from 14.04, you are most likely still running *upstart*, and the result of running the *systemctl* command is the output you got.

See my answer at [systemctl : comand not found 16.04 server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/818642/systemctl-comand-not-found-16-04-server/920241#920241) for more.

Comment: But this an Ubuntu container, which by default doesn't have systemd and wouldn't have upstart.

Comment: what? ubuntu has systemd by default

Comment: Stefan: I believe you are correct in the case of Docker.

Comment: knocte: my comment covers the case of upgrading from 14.04 (Upstart) to 16.04 (systemd). When performing the version upgrade, Upstart is not replaced with systemd for understandable reasons (like: not breaking the system). In retrospect, I realize the release upgrade process wouldn't be used in Docker. See the link I called out.

I see that a number of answers and comments fail to consider the specific case of Docker, and I'll look for that when answering in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the exact same error and then I run it successfully with `sudo`

```
sudo systemctl status ssh
```

Comment: you shouldn't need `sudo` for that. Seems like a coincidence. Can you please re-test?

Comment: @Zanna
`saif@sr-server:~$ systemctl status ssh`
`Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory`
`saif@sr-server:~$ sudo systemctl status ssh`
`[sudo] password for saif:`
`● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-01-19 23:38:14 PKT; 4min 4s ago
 Main PID: 18222 (sshd)
    Tasks: 15
   Memory: 32.7M
      CPU: 488ms`

Comment: Why -1? I just posted what worked for me.

Comment: downvote was not mine...

Comment: The question is about getting the `systemctl status ssh` command to run in the `ubuntu:16.04` docker container. SSH is not installed in that container by default. You also don't need `sudo` to run these commands in a docker container. Normal best practices in permission management are different between docker containers and normal OS's. I assume your answer is for normal Ubuntu installation.

Answer (score -3):

Inside docker container, I think you can update-rc.d if you are still struggling with systemd. I tried with update-rd.c and it works.

Comment: this is for system V not systemd