# systemctl : comand not found 16.04 server

Tags: server, 16.04, systemd

I am getting the error `systemctl: command not found` in Ubuntu 16.04 server.
How can I fix it?

I'm trying to run:

```
sudo systemctl start openvpn@server
```

Comment: Doesn’t the command line tell you what package to install? Have you tried it?

Comment: The executable should be located in `/bin/systemctl` and be able to run without specifying the full path. It is part of the `systemd` package which comes preinstalled with 16.04. Please show the output of `apt policy systemd` to verify you have the necessary package installed. Also show the output of `ls -l /bin/systemd` and `echo $PATH` please.

Answer (score 3):

Unless removed after installation of 16.04, */bin/systemctl* should be installed. It is part of the *systemd* package.

In Ubuntu 16.04, *init* is implemented as *systemd*. This replaces upstart by default, although a 16.04 system can be configured to use *upstart*.

Byte Commander is correct, but did not post his comment as the answer.

**An important exception:** If you *upgraded* from 14.04 to 16.04, then your system is still running *upstart*, not *systemd* and systemctl will not function as you're expecting in your question. I suspect this is the explanation for the problem you're having. If allowed to stand, the upgraded system will continue to develop problems when new software is added or updates are made by software that *assumes* systemd is used because the version number is 16.04, and all the other permutations of assumptions leading to errors that are possible. This is one case that argues for doing a clean install rather than upgrading if at all possible.

How can you tell if your system is running *systemd* or *upstart* as init?

```
# init --help
```

... and observe the output.

This article will help further, including instructions on switching between implementations of init: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers