# Updated 16.04 server to 18.04.1, now I see weird errors about missing files, failing to resolve dns, failing to connect to bus

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, systemd, dbus

Ok, so this is an upgrade from 16.04.1 LTS to 18.04.1 LTS, the server is headless. After the upgrade is finished, and a reboot is completed, the following happens:

Trying to upgrade packages only results in the following:

```
~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  policykit-1 screen smartmontools
3 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,081 kB of archives.
After this operation, 147 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y

(Reading database ... 159133 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../smartmontools_6.5+svn4324-1_amd64.deb ...
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
[...]
```

Is it Dbus it is talking about?
Anyway, how about a restore?

```
~$ sudo apt update
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'se.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'se.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'se.archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
W: Failed to fetch http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'se.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'se.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'se.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What? Is dns broken?

```
~$ wget www.google.com
--2018-11-10 01:55:16--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘www.google.com’
```

Looks like it. Hmm, ifconfig doesn't show dns. Google directs me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299241/ubuntu-18-04-server-how-to-check-dns-ip-server-setting-being-used) ,  let's try it.

```
~$ systemd-resolve --status
sd_bus_open_system: No such file or directory
```

Ok, I'm more and more lost now. Google now finds [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/813588/systemctl-failed-to-connect-to-bus-docker-ubuntu16-04-container), which is about docker, which is not my case, but also mentions a problem where systemd isnt pid 1:

```
~$ ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.1  0.1 159752  9116 ?        Ss   01:25   0:02 /sbin/init splash nomdmonddf nomdmonisw
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    01:25   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    01:25   0:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   01:25   0:00 [kworker/0:0H]
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    01:25   0:00 [rcu_sched]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    01:25   0:00 [rcu_bh]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    01:25   0:00 [migration/0]
root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    01:25   0:00 [watchdog/0]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    01:25   0:00 [watchdog/1]
[...]
```

I guess? Is this the root problem, or a symptom? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error on one OVH VPS server after upgrading to 18.04.01.
I have other very similar servers working fine after the upgrade, which helped me fix this.

Went down a rabbit hole and noticed:

```
sudo systemctl
...
systemd-logind.service     loaded failed failed
...
```

Which lead me to this site:
https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/systemd-logind-failures.44219/

I confirmed that my /var/run was not sym linked to /run , and it was on the other servers. This one had files in both places.

I symlinkd almost as suggested, fixing "directory not empty" errors in every line with:

```
mv -f /var/run/sudo/ts/* /run/sudo/ts/; rm -rf /var/run/sudo/ts; 
mv -f /var/run/sudo/* /run/sudo/; rm -rf /var/run/sudo; 
mv -f /var/run/* /run/; rm -rf /var/run; 
ln -s /run /var/run;
reboot
```

This step solved parts of the problem, such as:

```
$ systemd-resolve --status
```

But the DNS resolution was still failing, but working fine using resolve:

```
$ ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

$ systemd-resolve google.com
google.com: 216.58.213.174
```

As per the suggestion in https://superuser.com/questions/1317623/nslookup-failed-but-systemd-resolved-works

I changed my /etc/resolv.conf symlink from `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` to `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`

```
$ ls -l /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Feb 24  2017 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf

$ sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
$ sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf

$ ping google.com
PING google.com (216.58.204.238) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from par21s06-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.204.238): icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=9.11 ms
```

Everything is working now.