# Ubuntu 20.04.1 tracker-miner errors in Syslog

Tags: 20.04, syslog, xdg, tracker

New install of 20.04.1 running only pi.hole and unifi controller software. It’s Ubuntu desktop, but I’m basically running it headless.

I’ve noticed that I’m getting this set of tracker-miner related errors in syslog about twice a minute. I don’t really care if the tracker runs, although I don’t think I’m actually using it at all. But at a minimum I’d like to decrease the verbosity so I don’t see all of these errors.

I’ve looked around at disabling these services, but haven’t found anything that works yet, including trying to mask them via:
`systemctl --user mask tracker-store.service tracker-miner-fs.service tracker-miner-rss.service tracker-extract.service tracker-miner-apps.service tracker-writeback.service`

I tried to fix the XDG user directory location by running

`xdg-user-dirs-update`
Then editing user-dirs.dirs to modify the path names:

`XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"`
To
`XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="/home/matt/Downloads"`

But that also doesn’t seem to work.

Any thoughts on how to address this on a relatively new and clean Ubuntu desktop install?

```
cat /var/log/syslog | grep tracker:
Oct  9 08:28:17 pihole2 systemd[1034]: tracker-store.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Oct  9 08:28:17 pihole2 systemd[1034]: tracker-miner-fs.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 12.
Oct  9 08:28:17 pihole2 tracker-miner-f[1972]: Set scheduler policy to SCHED_IDLE
Oct  9 08:28:17 pihole2 tracker-miner-f[1972]: Setting priority nice level to 19
Oct  9 08:28:17 pihole2 tracker-store[1973]: Cannot initialize database: Could not open sqlite3 database:'/home/pihole/.cache/tracker/meta.db': unable to open database file
Oct  9 08:28:17 pihole2 systemd[1034]: tracker-store.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct  9 08:28:17 pihole2 systemd[1034]: tracker-store.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct  9 08:28:17 pihole2 tracker-miner-f[1972]: Unable to get XDG user directory path for special directory &DOCUMENTS. Ignoring this location.
Oct  9 08:28:17 pihole2 tracker-miner-f[1972]: Unable to get XDG user directory path for special directory &MUSIC. Ignoring this location.
Oct  9 08:28:17 pihole2 tracker-miner-f[1972]: Unable to get XDG user directory path for special directory &PICTURES. Ignoring this location.
Oct  9 08:28:17 pihole2 tracker-miner-f[1972]: Unable to get XDG user directory path for special directory &VIDEOS. Ignoring this location.
Oct  9 08:28:17 pihole2 tracker-miner-f[1972]: Unable to get XDG user directory path for special directory &DOWNLOAD. Ignoring this location.
Oct  9 08:28:17 pihole2 tracker-miner-f[1972]: Unable to get XDG user directory path for special directory &DOCUMENTS. Ignoring this location.
Oct  9 08:28:17 pihole2 tracker-miner-f[1972]: Unable to get XDG user directory path for special directory &MUSIC. Ignoring this location.
Oct  9 08:28:17 pihole2 tracker-miner-f[1972]: Unable to get XDG user directory path for special directory &PICTURES. Ignoring this location.
Oct  9 08:28:17 pihole2 tracker-miner-f[1972]: Unable to get XDG user directory path for special directory &VIDEOS. Ignoring this location.
Oct  9 08:28:17 pihole2 dbus-daemon[1045]: [session uid=998 pid=1045] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Tracker1' unit='tracker-store.service' requested by ':1.49' (uid=998 pid=1972 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs " label="unconfined")
Oct  9 08:28:17 pihole2 systemd[1034]: tracker-store.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
Oct  9 08:28:17 pihole2 tracker-store[1982]: Cannot initialize database: Could not open sqlite3 database:'/home/pihole/.cache/tracker/meta.db': unable to open database file
Oct  9 08:28:17 pihole2 systemd[1034]: tracker-store.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct  9 08:28:17 pihole2 systemd[1034]: tracker-store.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct  9 08:28:17 pihole2 tracker-miner-f[1972]: Couldn't create new Files miner: 'Failed to load SPARQL backend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying'
Oct  9 08:28:17 pihole2 systemd[1034]: tracker-miner-fs.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct  9 08:28:17 pihole2 systemd[1034]: tracker-miner-fs.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm in the same situation.

I think the main problem is that /home/pihole dir doesn't exists, and since pihole default shell is "nologin" you can't execute sudo for user and mask the services.

These are the steps I have followed to mask tracker services for pihole user

1. Create pihole's home directore and give pihole a shell.

   `sudo mkdir /home/pihole
   sudo usermod -s /bin/bash pihole`
2. Go to pihole shell

   `sudo -i -u pihole`
3. Initialise XDG_RUNTIME_DIR variable in order to run systemctl ([systemctl failed to connect to bus - docker ubuntu:16.04 container](https://askubuntu.com/questions/813588/systemctl-failed-to-connect-to-bus-docker-ubuntu16-04-container))

   `export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u)`

   In my case user id is 999 (I think this is pihole default user id)
4. Mask tracker services for pihole user.

   `systemctl --user mask tracker-store.service tracker-miner-fs.service tracker-miner-rss.service tracker-extract.service tracker-miner-apps.service tracker-writeback.service`
5. Restore nologin for pihole and delete pihole home dir (optional)

   `sudo usermod -s /usr/sbin/nologin pihole
   sudo rm -rf /home/pihole`
6. Reboot

Comment: I had to add a slash in front of run -> export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u)

Comment: You are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Also saw further errors in systemd logs with pihole user folders and pulseaudio.

Solved with:

1. `sudo mkhomedir_helper pihole`
2. Reboot

Checked systemd journal with:

```
journalctl -b -p err
```

Systemd journal now showed no pihole related errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo mkhomedir_helper pihole
```

This helped but it didn't stop failing until I also created an (empty) `.trackerignore` file in `/home/pihole`.

Both of the previous answers were helpful in solving this.