# syslog spammed by tracker-miner-f(s) errors

Tags: syslog

I did `tail -f /var/log/syslog`, and I'm noticing these errrors every minute:

```
Jan 11 13:06:34 Waveserver tracker-miner-f[2209925]: Set scheduler policy to SCHED_IDLE
Jan 11 13:06:34 Waveserver tracker-miner-f[2209925]: Setting priority nice level to 19
Jan 11 13:06:34 Waveserver tracker-miner-f[2209925]: Unable to get XDG user directory path for special directory &DOCUMENTS. Ignoring this location.
Jan 11 13:06:34 Waveserver tracker-miner-f[2209925]: Unable to get XDG user directory path for special directory &MUSIC. Ignoring this location.
Jan 11 13:06:34 Waveserver tracker-miner-f[2209925]: Unable to get XDG user directory path for special directory &PICTURES. Ignoring this location.
Jan 11 13:06:34 Waveserver tracker-miner-f[2209925]: Unable to get XDG user directory path for special directory &VIDEOS. Ignoring this location.
Jan 11 13:06:34 Waveserver tracker-miner-f[2209925]: Unable to get XDG user directory path for special directory &DOWNLOAD. Ignoring this location.
Jan 11 13:06:34 Waveserver tracker-miner-f[2209925]: Unable to get XDG user directory path for special directory &DOCUMENTS. Ignoring this location.
Jan 11 13:06:34 Waveserver tracker-miner-f[2209925]: Unable to get XDG user directory path for special directory &MUSIC. Ignoring this location.
Jan 11 13:06:34 Waveserver tracker-miner-f[2209925]: Unable to get XDG user directory path for special directory &PICTURES. Ignoring this location.
Jan 11 13:06:34 Waveserver tracker-miner-f[2209925]: Unable to get XDG user directory path for special directory &VIDEOS. Ignoring this location.
Jan 11 13:06:34 Waveserver dbus-daemon[174129]: [session uid=997 pid=174129] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Tracker1' unit='tracker-store.service' requested by ':1.157247' (uid=997 pid=2209925 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs " label="unconfined")
Jan 11 13:06:34 Waveserver systemd[174117]: tracker-store.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jan 11 13:06:34 Waveserver systemd[174117]: tracker-store.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 11 13:06:34 Waveserver systemd[174117]: Failed to start Tracker metadata database store and lookup manager.
Jan 11 13:08:04 Waveserver systemd[174117]: tracker-miner-fs.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jan 11 13:08:04 Waveserver systemd[174117]: tracker-miner-fs.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Jan 11 13:08:04 Waveserver systemd[174117]: Failed to start Tracker file system data miner.
Jan 11 13:08:05 Waveserver systemd[174117]: tracker-miner-fs.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 52638.
Jan 11 13:08:05 Waveserver systemd[174117]: Stopped Tracker file system data miner.
Jan 11 13:08:05 Waveserver systemd[174117]: Starting Tracker file system data miner...
Jan 11 13:08:05 Waveserver tracker-miner-f[2210020]: Set scheduler policy to SCHED_IDLE
Jan 11 13:08:05 Waveserver tracker-miner-f[2210020]: Setting priority nice level to 19
Jan 11 13:08:05 Waveserver tracker-miner-f[2210020]: Unable to get XDG user directory path for special directory &DOCUMENTS. Ignoring this location.
Jan 11 13:08:05 Waveserver tracker-miner-f[2210020]: Unable to get XDG user directory path for special directory &MUSIC. Ignoring this location.
Jan 11 13:08:05 Waveserver tracker-miner-f[2210020]: Unable to get XDG user directory path for special directory &PICTURES. Ignoring this location.
Jan 11 13:08:05 Waveserver tracker-miner-f[2210020]: Unable to get XDG user directory path for special directory &VIDEOS. Ignoring this location.
Jan 11 13:08:05 Waveserver tracker-miner-f[2210020]: Unable to get XDG user directory path for special directory &DOWNLOAD. Ignoring this location.
Jan 11 13:08:05 Waveserver tracker-miner-f[2210020]: Unable to get XDG user directory path for special directory &DOCUMENTS. Ignoring this location.
Jan 11 13:08:05 Waveserver tracker-miner-f[2210020]: Unable to get XDG user directory path for special directory &MUSIC. Ignoring this location.
Jan 11 13:08:05 Waveserver tracker-miner-f[2210020]: Unable to get XDG user directory path for special directory &PICTURES. Ignoring this location.
Jan 11 13:08:05 Waveserver tracker-miner-f[2210020]: Unable to get XDG user directory path for special directory &VIDEOS. Ignoring this location.
Jan 11 13:08:34 Waveserver tracker-miner-f[2210020]: Couldn't create new Files miner: 'Failed to load SPARQL backend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.Tracker1': timed out (service_start_timeout=120000ms)'
Jan 11 13:08:34 Waveserver systemd[174117]: tracker-miner-fs.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 11 13:08:34 Waveserver systemd[174117]: tracker-miner-fs.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 11 13:08:34 Waveserver systemd[174117]: Failed to start Tracker file system data miner.
Jan 11 13:08:34 Waveserver systemd[174117]: tracker-miner-fs.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 52639.
Jan 11 13:08:34 Waveserver systemd[174117]: Stopped Tracker file system data miner.
Jan 11 13:08:34 Waveserver systemd[174117]: Starting Tracker file system data miner...
Jan 11 13:08:34 Waveserver tracker-miner-f[2210055]: Set scheduler policy to SCHED_IDLE
Jan 11 13:08:34 Waveserver tracker-miner-f[2210055]: Setting priority nice level to 19
```

I have googled a bit but I couldn't find an anwser. `xdg-user-dirs-update` did not help. journalctl couldn't find tracker-miner-f(s), eventho it says `.service`. How can I fix this because I can't find anything in syslog as it is completely spamed with these errors. If you need anymore information just ask for it.

As someone asked on a different forum, no I don't have a special install. I didn't do something custom. While installing ubuntu, almost all the time, I was clicking continue. I didn't change default home dirs. There is only one user on the system (aside from users for programs), that was made while installing Ubuntu. I have never used a different user than that one that was made while installing.

`~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` is correctly setup (see comments).

Thanks.

Comment: Same question here, without answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1281399/ubuntu-20-04-1-tracker-miner-errors-in-syslog

Comment: Chack the contents of ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs

Comment: `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"` And I also found that question you gave a link to but it doesn't have an answer so...

Comment: Well, I already said "without answer" in my comment. That file looks OK. I would add that to the question (use "edit") so one already can exclude that as a cause of the issue.

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep dbus-user-session`  Is this package on your system?

Comment: `ii  dbus-user-session                                           1.12.16-2ubuntu2.1                                          amd64        simple interprocess messaging system (systemd --user integration)`