# How to run systemctl command inside docker container?

Tags: systemd, docker, dbus

I would like to run a docker container which will have the ability to run `systemctl` commands on its host.

Following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/813588/systemctl-failed-to-connect-to-bus-docker-ubuntu16-04-container) question I didn't find a solution that would work for me.

I have no hard limits on the docker base image, so using ubuntu-16.04 docker image for an ubuntu-16.04 host and ubuntu-18.04 docker image for an ubuntu-18.04 host is totally acceptable.

Answer (score 8):

After some investigation I was able to run a docker container with the ability to run `systemctl` command.

1. The following worked when running on an ubuntu:16.04 host:

   - ```
     sudo docker run --privileged -v /run/systemd/system:/run/systemd/system -v /bin/systemctl:/bin/systemctl -v /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket:/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket -it ubuntu:16.04 systemctl
     ```
   - ```
     sudo docker run --privileged -v /run/systemd/system:/run/systemd/system -v /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket:/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket -it ubuntu:16.04 systemctl
     ```
2. And on ubuntu:18.04 host:

   ```
   sudo docker run --privileged -v /run/systemd/system:/run/systemd/system -v /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket:/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket -it ubuntu:18.04 systemctl
   ```

   Since `systemctl` doesn't come with this image

Comment: A container needing systemd in it doesn't make much sense. If you need that, you might need to rethink the architecture. The purpose of a container is the run as a single service, if you have more than 1 service running in your container then you aren't using it properly. You can't use or think of containers as a normal OS or a virtual machine.

Comment: I want my container to be able to talk with its host systemd, in order to monitor and start/stop/restart the services , I don't want the actual container to use systemd

Comment: do you know about ubuntu 20.04？

Answer (score 3):

Thanks ofirule

Tried your solution on debian:10, your solution effectively allows to run the `systemctl` but it won't allow it to see/control the host's systemd processes. For this to work the `/sys/fs/cgroup` directory must also be mounted as a volume:

```
docker run -it --rm -v /bin/systemctl:/bin/systemctl -v /run/systemd/system:/run/systemd/system -v /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket:/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup debian:10 systemctl --no-pager status
```

With this i can control the host's systemd services and even do a shutdown/reboot through systemd.

This seems specific to Debian 10 and not needed for Ubuntu 18.04. Other Debian/Ubuntu versions might or might not need it.

Comment: Adding the `--privileged` flag didn't solve it?
I guess there are some differences between different OSes

Comment: No, the command runs fine but the host's services are not seen. Neither with `--privileged` nor with `-u 0:0`. Seems at least on Debian `/sys/fs/cgroup` is required. Will test it on an Ubuntu 18:04

Comment: Tested it on ubuntu:18.04 on aarch64 (don't have access to a ubuntu pc right now) and you are correct, mapping `/sys/fs/cgroup` seems not necessary. For aarch64 a bunch of libs must also be mapped to allow `systemctl` to run, but that is probably aarch64 specific which seems to have a more stripped down docker image.

I update my response to mention it is Debian10 specific.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Not allowed to comment. But this worked for my Ubuntu 18.04 setup:

```
sudo docker run --privileged \
-v /run/systemd/system:/run/systemd/system \
-v /lib/:/lib/ \
-v /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ \
-v /bin/systemctl:/bin/systemctl \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
-v /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket:/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket \
-it ubuntu:18.04 /bin/sh -c "systemctl restart openvpn.service; systemctl status openvpn.service"
```

If the command complains about `error while loading shared libraries: libip4tc.so.0:` -> run `locate libip4tc.so.0` to find out where this file is and mount the folder as a volume.